# UI-Router States: How to make app.run with $rootScope.$on minification safe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, bundling-and-minification

I'm using UI-Router in my app and to check if order of states are correct, I use a code like this:

```
.value('myRouteSteps', [
      { uiSref: 'myRoute.home', valid: true },
      { uiSref: 'myRoute.pageOne', valid: false },
      { uiSref: 'myRoute.pageTwo', valid: false },

])
.run([
        '$rootScope',
        '$state',
        'myRouteSteps',
        function ($rootScope, $state, myRouteSteps) {


            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

                var canGoToStep = false;

                var toStateIndex = _.findIndex(myRouteSteps, function (myRouteStep) {
                    return myRouteStep.uiSref === toState.name;

                });

                console.log('toStateIndex', toStateIndex)
                if (toStateIndex === 0) {
                    canGoToStep = true;
                } else {
                    canGoToStep = myRouteSteps[toStateIndex - 1].valid;
                }
                console.log('canGoToStep', toState.name, canGoToStep);

                // Stop state changing if the previous state is invalid
                if (!canGoToStep) {
                    // Abort going to step
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
]);
```

I'm getting error on line `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {` **if I do minification**.

So I've changed it to  `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ['event','toState','toParams','fromState','fromParams', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {`

Yet I'm still getting error.

**UPDATE:**

When I look at minified code I see this:

```
}]).run(["$rootScope", "$state", "orderSteps", function (n, t, i) {
        n.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (n, t) {
            var r = !1,
                u = _.findIndex(i, function (n) {
                    return n.uiSref === t.name
```

isn't right I guess...how to fix?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`_.findIndex` can return `-1` in the case where it is not found. `0` is the first item in the array, `-1` is not found.  This will cause problems here

```
if (toStateIndex === 0) {
    canGoToStep = true;
} else {
    canGoToStep = myRouteSteps[toStateIndex - 1].valid;
}
```

When `toStateIndex` is `-1` you will get index of out range exception.

You probably want something like this:

```
if (toStateIndex < 0) {
    canGoToStep = true;
} else {
    canGoToStep = myRouteSteps[toStateIndex].valid;
}
```

To explain how this could happen... When you first load your page, UI router will go to the `''` state, when it tries to go to `''` it triggers `$stateChangeStart`. `_.findIndex` cannot find `''` in `myRouteSteps` and `toStateIndex` becomes `-1`. `-1` is not equal to `0` so it falls in the `else` block, `-1 - 1` is `-2`, `myRouteSteps[-2]` is out of range.

Comment: No, there is no erronous possibility in my code for states that don't exist. That's not the problem, as you can see from above minified code $rootScope becomes toState in inline function (both changed to n in minification)..

Comment: That is fine, you never use `$state` in that scope so the variable is allowed to be overridden in that scope.  Because you never use `$state` in that function scope, it doesn't need to be there and you don't need a reference to it and the minifier knows that.

Comment: You are right, it seems to pass that part correctly when I run line by line in debugger, but then again it takes me to infinite loop error [Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D) it doesn't do that if I use unminified version.

Comment: Ok, I've cheked minified contents of n, t, i in debugger and they are not what they should be. $stateChangeStart becomes event in minified version, which is not supposed to. How can I inject parameters to an anonymous function so that it works with minification?

Comment: They are not injected the same way as services.  UI-router will call your callback function passing in the arguments in that order each and every time.  It doesn't matter what you call them or what they are named after minification.  The fact that `'$stateChangeStart'` which is a string is becoming a variable tells me there is a larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

After I've passed my file through [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) and diff with original file found out that one of di annotations was missing in state declaration.

I'll use ng-annotate from now on instead of trying to convert my Angular apps minification safe myself.